# Bridge Pattern - benefit of compilation in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns, compilation, bridge

It is said in **Design Patterns - Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software** book :

> In situations where there's only one implementation (one-to-one) ,creating an
>   abstract implementor class isn't necessary.This is a degenerate case
>   of the bridge pattern; there's a one-to-one relationship between
>   Abstraction and Implementor.Nevertheless,this seperation is still
>   useful when a change in the implementation of a class must not affect
>   its existing clients- that is they shouldn't have to be
>   recompiled,just relinked.

I doubt about the benefit of compile time because I can't imagine a case in Java where a change in implementation makes recompile its superclass (abstract in this case).

For example, if we have X extends Y and a client do :

```
Y y = new X();
```

A change in X does not mean a recompilation of Y (of course if we don't want to change the method signatures of X)

It is exactly the same thing when using Bridge Pattern :

```
YAbstraction yabstraction = new YRefinedAbstraction(new XImplementor());
```

A change in XImplementor does not mean a recompilation of YAbstraction.

So, according to me, this benefit does not take place in Java and for a one-to-one => no Bridge Pattern needed.

Perhaps a change in a subclass force superclass to be recompiled in other languages ? like SmallTalk and C++ ?

What are your opinions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the bridge pattern you have two class hierarchies: one for the Abstraction (e.g. Window with derived classes like DialogWindow and IconWindow) and one for the Implementor (e.g. WindowImpl with derived classes like XWindowImpl and PMWindowImpl). Implementor's interface should be hidden from the clients of the Abstraction. Normally, the Implementor provides low-level primitives and the Abstraction builds higher-level operations in terms of those primitives, thus in a well-layered system clients should have no need to see the low-level interface offered by the Implementor. If one day, it turns out that the interface offered by WindowImpl isn't general enough to accomodate new XYZWindowImpl, you retain the freedom to change it since WindowImpl should never be used directly by your clients but only by Window and its subclasses. Thus, the change in the interface of WindowImpl may require modifications to Window, but will not propagate to the clients. Also, one often hides the Implementor behind an Abstract Factory which is used to configure the bridge.

The advantage of the Bridge pattern you described depends on hiding of Implementor's interface from the clients of the Abstraction. In C++ you can easily hide Implementor's interface by simply not providing the header file. In Java you can make the Implementor an abstract class with package private members.

In C++ clients of the Abstraction will not need to be recompiled, only relinked. In Java, instead of linking you have class loading and thus all you need to do is reload the application with new settings and a new jar file.

Imagine for example a situation when a command line option or an environment variable is used by an Abstract Factory to configure the bridge with the right kind of ConcreteImplementor. In such case you simply need to reload the application with new command line/environment settings and a new jar file containing the new ConcreteImplementor. You can do this without recompiling client code.

Thus to provide direct answer to your question: also in Java the Bridge pattern does have the advantage described in the question. Possibly to even greater extent if you count the fact that no relinking ever takes place.

Comment: OP's point was specific to the case where there was only one implementation of the implementor class.

Comment: Thanks for this well-developed explanation :) So I sum up : A change in WindowImp only induce a change in Window and no need client to be recompiled => because only body of methods of Window class were changed (to adapt to the new WindowImp) and not methods signatures of Window Class,  am I right ?

Comment: @TedHopp That's right. I only referred to multiple ConcreteImplementors as an example reason we'd have to change Implementor's interface. There may be other reasons, also with a single ConcreteImplementor. For example, one might want to take advantage of new X capabilities in XWindowImpl and this may require changes to WindowImpl.

Comment: and for the case when Abstract Factory is used, I imagine that you'd place it into Window class and in its constructor you'd do : implementor = Factory.createConcreteImplementor("classname from command line option"). Is it what you have imagined?  Thanks you a lot :)

Comment: Almost. Usually a factory instance is created elsewhere and passed into a Window, so you'd have factory.createConcreteImplementor(). You can also pass a ready made WindowImpl instance after it is created by the factory somewhere else. Also, sometimes, a factory is a singleton and is readily accessible within Window constructor. The command line options or other settings are often given to or read by the factory. This is to separate responsibility: Windows should not be made responsible for reading settings controlling object creation. This responsibility belongs in the factory.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't have "linking" in the same way that C/C++ does. However, I think that the concept still applies: if the implementation class is in a separate library (.jar file) from the abstraction, then you don't have to repackage the .jar file containing the abstraction. This can simplify maintenance of a complex system.

Comment: Ok but what difference with the X,Y example : if Y is in A.jar and  and X is in B.jar, repackaging X does not mean a repackaging of Y, are you agree ?

Comment: @Mik378 - I agree with that. I think that there's only a very slight advantage (if any) to the entire pattern in the case of there being only one possible implementation. The idea I had in mind was that the (abstract) implementor class would be packaged with the abstraction class, while the concrete implementor class would be in a separate .jar file. (Note that "abstraction class" != "abstract class". The terminology here is, unfortunately, somewhat confusing, but that's what the GoF bequeathed to us.)

Comment: Yes, I know that abstraction class for design concept isn't the same concept at all as abstract class in Java. I use term "abstract class" for the case where there is no bridge pattern, it means a simple hierarchy.

Comment: Dredging up a very old answer here, but this answer is about separating the implementation class from its abstraction, whereas the GoF quote in the OP specifically states, "_creating an abstract implementor class isn't necessary._" Would you agree there is no benefit to the Bridge Pattern in Java without an abstract implementor class?